# How to concatenate or join items in a list of lists

Tags: python

I would like to concatenate/join items in a large list of lists:

```
list = [['tulip', 'rose', 'red'], ['yellow'], ['lemon'], ['red', 'apple', 'sweet']]
```

My desired output is:

```
list_join = [['tulip rose red'], ['yellow lemon'], ['red apple sweet']]
```

Comment: what exactly is `[[tulip rose red], [yellow lemon], [red apple sweet]]` ? That isn't a valid python expression.

Comment: do you mean `['tulip rose red', 'yellow lemon', 'red apple sweet']`
?

Comment: What did you try so far? `join` is a built-in function.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the desired output I assume you meant to write `['yellow', 'lemon']`? So all in all:

```
list = [['tulip', 'rose', 'red'], ['yellow', 'lemon'], ['red', 'apple', 'sweet']]
```

Am I right?
Anyways you can join the elements of each list by using the join-function with the separator **' '**, e.g. `' '.join(['tulip', 'rose', 'red'])` equals `'tulip rose red'`.

Maybe this answers your question:

```
list_join = [[' '.join(el)] for el in list]
```

You might want to drop the brackets around `' '.join(el)` and simplify the result to `['tulip rose red', 'yellow lemon', 'red apple sweet']`.

By the way, by choosing *list* as a variable name you overwrite the list-function's name.

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for.